# Compare two dataframes and keep a specific datetime range of another

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, compare

I have two dataframes with timestamps. I want to select the timestamps from `df1` that equal the timestamps `'start_show'` of `df2` but also keep all the timestamps of `df1` 2 hours before and 2 hours after (of `df1`) where the timestamps are equal.

`df1:`

```
       van_timestamp         weekdag
2880    2016-11-19 00:00:00    6
2881    2016-11-19 00:15:00    6
2882    2016-11-19 00:30:00    6
...            ...            ...
822349  2019-11-06 22:45:00    3
822350  2019-11-06 23:00:00    3
822351  2019-11-06 23:15:00    3
```

`df2:`

```
            einde_show               start_show
255     2016-01-16 22:00:00      2016-01-16 20:00:00
256     2016-01-23 21:30:00      2016-01-23 19:45:00
257     2016-01-26 21:30:00      2016-01-26 19:45:00
...                ...                    ...
1111    2019-12-29 18:30:00      2019-12-29 17:00:00
1112    2019-12-30 15:00:00      2019-12-30 13:30:00
1113    2019-12-30 18:30:00      2019-12-30 17:00:00
```

`df1` contains a timestamp every 15 minutes of every day whereas `df2['start_show']` contains just a single timestamp per day.

So ultimately what I want to achieve is that for every timestamp of `df2` I have the corresponding timestamp of `df1` +- 2 hours.

So far I've tried:

```
df1['van_timestamp'][df1['van_timestamp'].isin(df2['start_show'])]
```

This selects the right timestamps. Now I want to select everything from `df1` in the range of

```
+ pd.Timedelta(2, unit='h')
- pd.Timedelta(2, unit='h')
```

But I'm not sure how to go about this. Help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working (ugly fix). I created a datetime range

```
dates = [pd.date_range(start = df2['start_show'].iloc[i] - pd.Timedelta(2, unit='h'), end = df2['start_show'].iloc[i], freq = '15T') for i in range(len(evs_data))]
```

Which I then unlisted:

```
dates = [i for sublist in dates for i in sublist]
```

Afterwards I compared the dataframe with this list.

```
relevant_timestamps = df1[df1['van_timestamp'].isin(dates)]
```

If anyone else has a better solution, please let me know!